# Grafana variable: Return all Elastic documents when selecting "All" and the attribute might be an empty list

Tags: elasticsearch, grafana

Take the following Lucene query:

```
provision_org.keyword:$provision_org
```

If `$provision_org` has the value "hello", the query returns all documents where `provision_org` (a list) contains the item "hello". So far so good.

If `$provision_org` has the value "*", the query returns all documents where `provision_org` (a list) contains an element.

Is there any value that I could assign to `$provision_org` so that all documents are returned, even those where `provision_org` is an empty list?

The reason I want this value is to set it as the "Custom All value" in the Grafana (multi-value) variable. Obviously what I want is to have an "All" option that effectively results in ignoring that particular variable. (I'm not really certain that the "Custom All value" is the correct way to do that.)

Comment: I assume the [exist query](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/query-dsl-exists-query.html) is not something you want to be using ? you want a pure lucene search query ?

Comment: @Paulo Yes, Grafana doesn't seem to be supporting the Query DSL, it only supports Lucene.

Comment: Hmmm, I would be very surprise. All query done on Elasticsearch API has to be done using the query dsl. A Lucene query is translated into a query dsl. I think we might need more context where/what you work with. Where are your writing your query ?

Comment: @Paulo I'm writing the query on a Grafana text field that is labeled "Query" and has the placeholder "Lucene query". In order to answer your question (thanks for asking!) I investigated and found out it's making a `query_string` query, which is well documented, but still I can't find out a solution.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This might help:

`* OR (NOT _exists_:provision_org.keyword)`

[image]

[image]

[image]

Or you can use `Ad hoc filter`, but way to use it is quite different from variable

[image]

[image]

Comment: Thanks! This seems to work, but it is an ugly hack—similar to an SQL injection. Conceivably it could stop working from one Grafana version to another. So there is no "correct" way to do it?

Comment: Well, I agree that this is ugly :p, because I have to put a expression there where should be a basic string value. Yet I don't see why it "could stop working from one Grafana version to another". For Grafana never generate lucene query (like it generates aggregate query), it simply put what ever in `Query` textbox to `stringQuery` field, there isn't any feature to be changed.

Comment: Hope there is a better answer though. ;D

Comment: @AntonisChristofides Just came up with another idea, I've appended it to my post. Hope it would help.

Comment: Thanks, I had looked at ad hoc filters but they wouldn't work in my case. BTW, I think it would be better to use `* OR (NOT _exists_:provision_org)`, i.e. without the `.keyword` (I'm not certain it works with `.keyword`, but it's certainly not needed).

Comment: @AntonisChristofides Sorry for bothering. If you found this answer helpful, I'll be grateful for getting first pot of bounty of me. XD